# Casting an unknown enum value to default enum in spring boot mongo repository actions

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have problem while casting an unknown enum to a default enum in spring boot while using mongo repository.

This is the enum.

```
public enum EventType implements Serializable
{
  WORKDONE("WORKDONE"),
  ODRCOM("ODRCOM"),
  EXECUTED("EXECUTED"),
  REBOOK("REBOOK"),
  MANUAL("MANUAL"),
  UNKNOWN("UNKNOWN");
  
  private String value;
  EventType(final String type) {
    this.value = type;
  }
  
  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return value;
  }
}
```

And here is my model class

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Event {
  
  //other properties
  
  @JsonProperty("eventType")
  private EventType eventType;
  
  @JsonIgnore
  private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  
  @JsonProperty("eventType")
  public EventType getEventType() {
    return eventType;
  }
  
  
  @JsonProperty("eventType")
  public void setEventType(String eventType) {
    this.eventType = Optional.ofNullable(EventType.valueOf(eventType)).orElse(EventType.UNKNOWN);
  }
  
  //other getters and setters
  
}
```

Here is the mongo repository

```
public interface EventRepository extends MongoRepository<Event, String> {
  
}
```

The document stored in the db is of the following stucture

```
{
...
"eventType" : "REBOOK1",
...
}
```

Please note that the REBOOK1 is not a valid enum. But the setter should be able to able to cast anything else to type UNKNOWN.
However it gives this exception everytime

**No enum constant dk.nuuday.ossieventprocessor.app.model.EventType.REBOOK1**

I have tried with adding a custom converter as a configuration but no luck
Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: JsonProperty are not working for Mongodb. Usually it is said, that you should create Mongodb converter for your custom type, but it is never worked for me in case of enums.